# Merge XML files in a XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to merge several XML files in a single XDocument object.

Merge does not exist in XDocument object. I miss this.

Has anyone already implemented a Merge extension method for XDocument, or something similar ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I tried a bit myself :

```
var MyDoc = XDocument.Load("File1.xml");
MyDoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load("File2.xml").Root.Elements());
```

I dont know whether it is good or bad, but it works fine to me :-)

Answer (score 3):

Being pragmatic, `XDocument` vs `XmLDocument` isn't all-or-nothing (unless you are on Silverlight) - so if `XmlDoucument` does something you need, and `XDocument` doesn't, then perhaps use `XmlDocument` (with `ImportNode` etc).

That said, even with `XDocument`, you could presumably use `XNode.ReadFrom` to import each, then simply `.Add` it to the main collection.

Of course, if the files are big, `XmlReader/XmlWriter` might be more efficient... but more complex. Fortunately, `XmlWriter` has a `WriteNode` method that accepts an `XmlReader`, so you can navigate to the first child in the `XmlReader` and then just blitz it to the output file. Something like:

```
    static void AppendChildren(this XmlWriter writer, string path)
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            int targetDepth = reader.Depth + 1;
            if(reader.Read()) {
                while (reader.Depth == targetDepth)
                {
                    writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
                }                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I think I have found something that works with less code.

Answer (score 3):

Merge all xml files from dir to one XDocument

```
public static XDocument MergeDir(string xmlDir)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<root></root>");
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(xmlDir);
    if (directory.Exists)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.Extension == ".xml")
            {
                xdoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(file.FullName).Root.Elements());
            }
        }
    }

    return xdoc;
}
```